# How I can mark lines between two text strings using regular expressions option in Notepad ++?

Tags: notepad++

I am trying to simply mark and replace all the lines in in Notepad++ file enclosed by two words/text e.g. PERMI & EQUALSI (see attached figure). How I can do that using regular expressions searching option?

Thanks and appreciate your support in advance,
Muni

Example:-

```
PERMI ALL  
*MOD   1:61   1:61  103:104     * 0      
PERMJ  EQUALSI
*MOD   1:61   1:61  103:104     * 0
PERMK  EQUALSI * 0.1
*MOD   1:61   1:61  103:104     * 0
```

Comment: As is, your question is unanswerable! Edit your question and add sample file, expected result and what you have tried and what doesn't work.

Comment: Noted. I've edited the question now

Comment: Please, don't give example with an image, we can't reproduce the test. Put the example as text **and show what is your expected result**

Comment: Find: `PERMI ALL[\s\S]+?EQUALSI` ; Replace: `LEAVE EMPTY`

Answer (score 1):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `PERMI ALL[\s\S]+?EQUALSI`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
PERMI ALL       # literally
[\s\S]+?        # 1 or more any character, not greedy
EQUALSI         # literally
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: thanks for your solution I do not understand why it is not validated because it works like a charm.